# How do I only put dependencies into a specific folder for yarn?

Tags: javascript, npm, gulp, bower, yarnpkg

### Background

I have been using `bower` for handling dependencies, however now I would like to migrate to `yarn`. The main hurdle I am having is migrating from the below `.bowerc` file to `.yarnrc`.

*.bowerrc*

```
{
     "directory": "src/vendors"
}
```

The issue is I could make a `.yarnrc` file, like below that will put **any** dependency into `src/vendors`, but that **includes** devDependencies.

*.yarnrc*

`--modules-folder src/vendors`

### Question

How do I only put **dependencies** into `src/vendors` and put`devDependencies` in `node_modules`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`--production` option](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install#toc-yarn-install-production-true-false) to tell **yarn** which dependencies you want to install; if set to `true` it will just install `dependencies`.

So in your `src` folder make a `.yarnrc` file with the following content:

```
--modules-folder vendors
--production true
```

and in your project dir, in `.yarnrc` file, set `--production` to *false*:

```
--production false
```

folder structure:

```
.
├── package.json
├── src
│   └── .yarnrc
└── .yarnrc
```

Comment: After creating both .yarnrc files, make sure you run yarn install on the src directory first and only after on the root directory. If doing it the other way around, it will wipe out everything in the root directory's node_modules folder. This issue is documented [here](http://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/1684)

Answer (score 6):

An alternative way to accomplish the same thing as in the answer above (but without the `.yarnrc` files) is by adding two different scripts to `package.json`, something along these lines:

```
  "scripts": {
      "install-depends": "yarn install --production=true --modules-folder ./src/vendors",
      "install-devDepends": "yarn install --production=false"
   }
```

Then you just run them in that same order (if you do it the other way around, it will wipe out everything in the `node_modules`:

1. `yarn run install-depends`
2. `yarn run install-devDepends`